# Считать файл в observable list

Tags: java, файлы, javafx, observablecollection

Имеется следующий код:

```
initData();
System.out.println(booksData);

    nameProduct.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Books, String>("name"));
    priceProduct.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Books, Integer>("number"));

    productTableView.setItems(booksData);
}

private void initData() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c://JavaFiles/test.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("")) {
            booksData.add(line);
        }
    }
```

Сущность `Books`

```
public class Books {
    private String name;
    private Integer number;

    public Books (String name, Integer number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Books(){

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Мне нужно в методе `initData()` считать файл в коллекцию `booksData`. В файле хранятся строки следующего содержания:

Книги 2

Comment: Если имена книг не содержат пробелов, то можно так: `String[] tokens = line.split(" "); booksData.add(new Books(tokens[0], Interger.parse(tokens[1])));`.

Comment: Ругается на 1 токен

Comment: Error:(98, 33) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int

Comment: Кажется надо `Integer.parseInt` вместо `Integer.parse`

Comment: Исправил. Но выдает ошибку

Comment: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В предположении, что строки в файле имеют формат `<имя книги> <число>`, код может выглядеть так:

```
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    line = line.trim();
    if (!line.isEmpty()) {
        int indexOfLastSpace = line.lastIndexOf(' ');
        String bookName = line.substring(0, indexOfLastSpace);
        int bookNumber = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(indexOfLastSpace + 1));
        booksData.add(new Book(bookName, bookNumber));
    }
}
```

Здесь используются несколько полезных методов, а именно:

1. [`String::trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) — удалить пробелы из начала и конца строки
2. [`String::isEmpty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--)
3. [`String::lastIndexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf-int-) — индекс последнего вхождения символа
4. [`String::substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) — получить подстроку из полуинтервала `[start, end)`
5. [`Integer::parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) — преобразовать строку в число

Comment: А вот это то что надо! А если в имени книги имеются пробелы?

Comment: Всё нормально будет, обратите внимание на строку `line.lastIndexOf(' ')`, мы находим последний пробел, после него точно идёт число. Всё что до этого последнего пробела — имя книги, там могут быть пробелы.

Comment: Ты снова мне помог!))) как и вчера))

Comment: привет!Свяжись со мной, пожалуйста, есть вопрос...https://vk.com/mishustiq